# HttpUrlConnection кириллица

Tags: java, android

На сервер передаю имя и мыло пользователя. Латиница работает хорошо, а вот кириллица - на 4.4 приходят ??????? вместо символов, на версиях старше - все нормально. Где искать проблему?

Передачу делаю так

```
URL url = new URL(url_string);
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) 
url.openConnection();

connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,ru;q=0.5");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=utf-8");
```

Может проблема в свойстве Accept-Language? Что ставить если язык может быть и русский и английский?
Для проверки кодировки вставил эти две строки - кодировка utf-8, но кириллица адекватно не передается, причем именно на старых андроидах.

```
byte[] b = url_string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
url_string = new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: А где *имя и мыло*? query? - покажите тогда как формируете строку `url_string`.

Comment: request.execute(myURL + "?name=" + name + "&key=" + email +"&version=" + BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);

Comment: Тогда причём здесь `HttpURLConnection`? У вас сервер получает `??????` или приложение в ответ от сервера? Если первое см. ответ dSH, если второе покажите как получаете строку из ответа и проверьте его заголовки - какую кодировку сервер передаёт.

Comment: сервер получает ??????

Comment: Я так понимаю, что `request.execute` - это из Apache `HttpClient`, который на Андроиде давно объявлен устаревшим и вырезан из SDK. Если вы включили его в проект, то на старых устройствах (по приоритету загрузки классов) используется системный древней версии, а на новых, где его нет используется подключенный к проекту. Из-за этого и разница в поведении. Вообще лучше его не использовать. А query-параметры должны быть закодированы как указано в ответе методом `URLEncoder.encode()` или другими средствами.

Answer (score 2):

Одна из возможных причин - забыли кириллицу перекодировать через URLEncoder.
Стандарт rfc3986 требует перекодирования, так как он использует только US-ASCII
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986

```
URLEncoder.encode(value1, "UTF-8")
```

В Вашем случае это видимо поле name